# Get smallest difference between consecutive numbers of a textbox

Tags: c#

I have a textbox on my design form that have multiple numbers of double data type. I have a class that has a method to calculate smallest difference (positive or negative) between two consecutive numbers.

```
public decimal FindSmallestPriceChange()
{

}
```

On my form there is a label to display the result and a button event that calls the above method to calculate and display the smallest change between consecutive numbers in the text box.

```
private void btnSmallest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblSmallest.Text = aAnalyzer.FindSmallestPriceChange().ToString();
}
```

I have an array mentioned in the form class :

```
decimal[] prices = Array.ConvertAll(stringPrices, decimal.Parse);
```

I know I have to use for loop in my FindSmallest method but I don't know how to use the elements from the text box on design form in my separate class.

Can someone guide me on the right path on this.

Comment: `FindSmallestPriceChange` method should accept an array of numbers as parameter and perform operation on that. You can call the method as `aAnalyzer.FindSmallestPriceChange(prices).ToString();`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods

Answer (score 0):

The structure could be something like the following.

```
private void btnSmallest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var stringPrices = new List<string>();
   stringPrices.Add(comboBox1.Text);
   stringPrices.Add(comboBox2.Text);

   //TODO add error handling
   decimal[] prices = Array.ConvertAll(stringPrices, decimal.Parse);

   lblSmallest.Text = aAnalyzer.FindSmallestPriceChange(prices).ToString();
}

(...)

public static decimal FindSmallestPriceChange(IEnumerable<decimal> prices)
{
    // There are many ways to do this. Here is one.
    var sorted = prices.ToList();
    sorted.Sort();

    if( prices.Count() < 2 ) return 0;

    decimal min = sorted[1] - sorted[0];
    for(int i = 2; i < sorted.Count() - 1 ; i++ ) {
        var diff = sorted[i-1] - sorted[i];
        if( diff < min ) min = diff;
    }
    return min;
}
```

## Test

```
Console.WriteLine(FindSmallestPriceChange(new []{66.6m}));
Console.WriteLine(FindSmallestPriceChange(new []{1m, 2m}));
Console.WriteLine(FindSmallestPriceChange(new []{1.1m, 4.4m, 2.2m}));
Console.WriteLine(FindSmallestPriceChange(new []{4.4m, -1.1m, 0m, 1.1m, 2.2m, }));
```

Output

```
0
1
1.1
-1.1
```

Comment: Why sort them, if it says 'consecutive'?

Comment: I didn't take 'consecutive' in the precise meaning of the word.